# is "millonarism" a valid English word?

Tags: translation

I've seen in my language the word "millonarismo" being mentioned several times but with quotations marks. Then I had the idea of using the translator to input "millonarism" to see if it translated into something in spanish and it doubtfully translated it into "millonarismo". I looked for examples of the use "millonarism" in English and I couldnt find any. Now I have both doubts, my original doubt in spanish and this other one, *is "millonarism" a valid English word?* or the english translator is taking it as valid input wrongly? Note: the translator suggests "did you mean millenarism?"

Comment: What does the word you are trying to translate mean?

Comment: Google tells me the word you're looking for is millionaire. https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wT#auto/en/millonarismo Did you try to translate the word from Spanish into English?

Comment: but millionarie translates to millonario, not to millonarism.

Comment: it's supposed to mean the lifestyle of a millionarie, or something like that

Comment: others argue it means "aspiration to become a millionarie"

Comment: One person claims a person called William D Howells (who I ignore who he is) used it in the XIX century

Comment: Short answer: "millonarism" is not a word in English.  Without more context, it's really hard to tell what you might be looking for.  "Millionaireism" might mean "the state, condition, doctrine, or theory of millionaires", but it is virtually unknown.

Comment: Would you [edit] your question to include the information in your comments please?

Comment: The proper spelling in English is ***millionairism*** but it does not exist in Spanish. You got the spelling wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/millionairism) millionairism is actually a word, but it's not a word that's ever likely to be used in conversation.  English speakers will use different words instead, like: elite, upper class, the one percent, the rich, the powerful, posh, etc.

Comment: The "ismo" ending indicates it is not describing the group of millionaires, but rather the "spirit" of that group.  It is not the people themselves, but how they think and act.

Comment: Yes, and in Spanish, it does not exist per se. But it can be coined.

Comment: English speakers would not use words like elite, upper class, the one percent, the rich, the powerful, posh.  Rather, they would use words like elitism, classist, entitlement, entrepreneurialism (or entrepreneurial spirit), noblesse oblige, privilidge, etc.  These describe the mindset, not the people themselves.

Answer (score 1):

"Millionarism" (or actually **"millionairism"**) is a word in the dictionary, but it's not in common use in the way you describe.  Still, that doesn't mean it *can't* become common.  People make up new words all the time, or use old words in new and unusual ways, or combine two words into some new word that's a combination of the two, often with additional nuance.

For example ["Trumpism"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/trumpism) is a word that variously means *"the words and policies of Donald Trump"* or *"an outrageous lie told with sincerity, akin to numerous statements by Donald Trump"*.  Trumpism didn't really exist before 2016 (and possibly not even before 2017) but now it's inescapable.

You have yet to define what millionarism *means*, though, so it's probable there's already a word in English for this concept. For example, if it means "the kind of attitude or lifestyle that makes someone a millionaire" then possibilities are:

> (the) [millionaire mentality](https://www.google.com/search?q=millionaire%20mentality&oq=millionaire%20mentality&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l6j0i22i30k1l4.47162.48000.0.48359.8.8.0.0.0.0.164.830.1j6.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.7.824...0i20i263k1.0.FTXfnCfkvu0)
>
> (the) [millionaire mindset](https://www.google.com/search?q=millionaire%20mindset&oq=millionaire%20mindset&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4464j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

and others.

Comment: This is a very Andrewesque answer.

Comment: It is a word in English. It's in the dictionary.

Comment: @Lambie so it is.  Edited.

Comment: @Lambie - It's a word in [very few dictionaries](https://onelook.com/?w=millionairism&ls=a), apparently (as opposed to a word like, say, [millionaire](https://onelook.com/?w=millionaire&ls=a)).

Comment: @J.R. What are you saying? I said Andrew did not spell the  word correctly and now he has corrected it. I had said it WAS in the dictionary.

Comment: @Lambie - What does "in the dictionary" mean? If there are twenty-seven online dictionaries, and the word is found in only two of them, is it fair to say that the word is "in the dictionary"? I suppose it is, but I think it's worth pointing out how commonly-listed the word is (or isn't).

Comment: @J.R. I am saying I agree with Andrew. The word is the kind of thing you might see once in a blue moon; it is arcane. My point was more about the confusion re the spelling by the OP.

Comment: @Lambie - I was curious, so I looked it up. I discovered it's in a couple dictionaries, but not in many. So, essentially, I'm agreeing with you, but just adding the tidbit that it's not only uncommon in usage, but even uncommon in dictionaries!

Comment: @J.R. I don't doubt that for one second. It ain't common in Spanish either. It's just making an ism out of the word millionaire. Like so many other isms.